Is prayer at all a mitzvah for Bnei Noach?
I’m curious whether or not prayer, not in the organized structured form of the Amidah but prayer in general, is considered by Halacha to at all be a mitzvah for Bnei Noach? If so, are there any structures which are recommended to the prayer (like saying amen and/or Hashem’s name) or is the mere intentionality to make a prayer enough?

וַהֲבִיאוֹתִ֞ים אֶל־הַ֣ר קָדְשִׁ֗י וְשִׂמַּחְתִּים֙ בְּבֵ֣ית תְּפִלָּתִ֔י עוֹלֹתֵיהֶ֧ם וְזִבְחֵיהֶ֛ם לְרָצ֖וֹן עַֽל־מִזְבְּחִ֑י כִּ֣י בֵיתִ֔י בֵּית־תְּפִלָּ֥ה יִקָּרֵ֖א לְכָל־הָעַמִּֽים: Whether or not it's a mitzva, it's a fundamental part of any religious person's relationship with God.

Also Shlomo: וְגַם֙ אֶל־הַנׇּכְרִ֔י אֲשֶׁ֛ר לֹא־מֵעַמְּךָ֥ יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל ה֑וּא וּבָ֛א מֵאֶ֥רֶץ רְחוֹקָ֖ה לְמַ֥עַן שְׁמֶֽךָ׃ כִּ֤י יִשְׁמְעוּן֙ אֶת־שִׁמְךָ֣ הַגָּד֔וֹל וְאֶת־יָֽדְךָ֙ הַחֲזָקָ֔ה וּֽזְרֹעֲךָ֖ הַנְּטוּיָ֑ה וּבָ֥א וְהִתְפַּלֵּ֖ל אֶל־הַבַּ֥יִת הַזֶּֽה...

@DoubleAA that wasn't the question..

1kings8
King Solomon prays over the temple.
In his prayer he separates the prayers offered by Israel and the prayers made by ‘all men’.
An answer to a sincere prayer offered to HaShem by ‘any man’ was Solomon’s prayer. HaShem ‘knoweth the hearts of the children of man. “Hear thou in heaven thy dwelling place, and do according to all that the stranger calleth to thee for:“
Additionally, gentiles are allowed to maintain their own altar and attempt sacrificial korban unto HaShem. One may judge if HaShem will bring blessing to the gentile.
Isaiah 56 states as well that the foreigners that love HaShem will be brought onto His sacred mount.
“For My House shall be called
A house of prayer for all peoples”.
